# Getting an "unresolved reference" error

Tags: python-3.x, reference, pycharm

I keep getting an "unresolved reference" error even though I made a statement to it.

```
verb_dict = {"say": say, "examine": examine}
```

The error is after the `examine`:

```
def examine(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        return GameObject.objects[noun].get_desc()
    else:
        return "There is no {}".format(noun)
```

Did I do something wrong when coding it?

I am also using pycharm community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem in PyCharm 2016.14 I run the following code with no issue:

```
class GameObject:
    class_name = ""
    objects = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        GameObject.objects[self.class_name] = self


def examine(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        return GameObject.objects[noun].get_desc()
    else:
        return "There is no {}".format(noun)

print(examine('try'))
```

Output is

```
>>> There is no try
```

Comment: I answered with the GameObject class you asked for. Maybe it can help.

Comment: I didn't give you the whole code, maybe that is the problem. I only gave you a part where I think the error is. Would you like the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the GameObject class.
I don't see a problem in there.If you need more tell me.

```
class GameObject:
    class_name = ""
    desc = ""
    objects = {}
    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        GameObject.objects[self.class_name] = self
```